# What are the differences between fieldquery vs termquery in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

What are the differences and similarities between fieldquery and termquery

```
    FilterBuilders.queryFilter(QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("truckName", "joshi"));
    FilterBuilders.queryFilter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("truckName", "joshi"));
```

Both returning same results.
Please give an examples

Comment: Which version of the API are you using?  The QueryBuilders.fieldQuery isn't in 1.0 or 1.1 as far as I can tell.

Comment: current version : 1.1.1
previous version was 0.90 --this version returned same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A term query is looking for an exact match of a terms field without doing any analysis of the parameter.

It looks like the fieldQuery (from http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-field-query.html) is a simple form of query_string on a specific field, so it would be doing analysis.

The two would act the same for single word "truckName", but the termQuery would be faster.

Comment: **truckName** is field name ,**joshi** is the string to be searched.